# How to figure out mAh battery needed for cheap string lights for x amount of time?

Tags: voltage, amperage

First, not only is it a question for a specific use case, I would like to either be pointed in the direction of a resource to learn, or a short explanation to help learn.

I ordered a set of string "fairy lights" from amazon and within the specs I see it runs on 3 AA batteries with additional specs of 4.5 V and 3 W. The order comes with TWO units, that I would like to string together off a single source.

Taking apart the unit there is a switch and 10 Ω resistors (brown, black, black, gold)

I would like to power these two units, as one, for 24 hours. With that, how do I figure out the voltage and the amps needed to determine the mAh battery needed? How does, if it does, the resistor come into play? Is a different resistor needed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Remember: Power In = Power Out + losses

Comment: If you edit your question with additional details your question might be reopened. For example try to provide a schematic or layout of the existing lamp circuit and perhaps your proposed re-design. A very good schematic editor is available within this forum, click on the small circuit icon in the group of editing options.

Answer (score 1):

Very roughly: assuming the specs are correct (you can measure that), and assuming that stringing together the two units means they are connected in parallel, so that both run at 4.5 V, would mean that the two units (3 W each) at 4.5 V draw 6 W / 4.5 V = 1.33 A.

So for 24 hours you would need a 4.5 V battery with a capacity of 1.33 A · 24 h = 32 Ah.

You will never get all the quoted capacity from a battery, and there are always losses, so you should add capacity to compensate; I would just add 50%, or even double it.

Comment: @jobiin - Consider staying with two battery sets, just switch to D size alkaline cells.

Answer (score 0):

The battery must provide energy to a load, of power P, for a time T.
The nominal voltage of the battery is Vcc.
Based on the definition of direct electric current I,
the electric charge supplied is: Q=I∙T.
Given that 1∙Coulomb= 1A∙s= 1A∙hr/3600 so 1Ah=3600Coulomb.
The electric charge supplied to the user in the time T is Q=P∙T/Vcc.
For example: T= 12h, the power dissipated by the load is equal to 100W, then the energy supplied by the battery in the time T is equal to: E=P∙T=1.2kWh=4.32MJ and the charge supplied in this time is equal to Q= E/Vcc=100Ah.
Without taking into account the fact that the battery discharges in this time and therefore the actual voltage of the battery is lower than the nominal voltage as time goes by. Therefore a 200Ah battery should be used to ensure that the load receives the required energy for the requested time.

In the case of LEDs, if each LED dissipates a power of P=20mW with a total supply LED string of Vcc=12V and the number of LEDs is N=100, it can be deduced that the total dissipated power is PT=N∙P=2W, so if the time when the LEDs are on is 24hr, you will need to use a battery with a charge of at least P∙T/Vcc=2W∙24hr/12V= 4Ah or 4000mAh, but it would be advisable to double this value to ensure that the load receives the required energy for the requested time.

Comment: Asterix mark is translated to start of italic text. You need “\\*”.

Comment: @winny OK! I've used ∙.